# WSO2 Remove Blank Spaces from beginning of text file

Tags: wso2, vfs, smooks

I have written a WSO2 integration which calls an API, grabs the properties I want from that API call, puts together a payload, passes that payload to a smooks mediator, which right pads each value with an appropriate number of spaces, and then writes to a .txt file.  Everything is working GREAT - except - the beginning of each row in my .txt file is pre-pended with several blank spaces.  So the file looks like this:

```
     value value value value
     value value value value
```

rather than this:

```
value value value value
value value value value
```

the portion of my smooks generator that pads each element looks like this:

```
<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="Employee180">
     <ftl:template>
          <!--${.vars["Employee180"].RecordType?right_pad(3)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace1?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].ContractNumber?right_pad(6)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace2?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].EmployeeIDNumber?right_pad(9)?replace("-","")}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace3?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].EmployeeName?right_pad(24)}${.vars["Employee180"].DateOfBirth?right_pad(10)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace4?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].DateOfEmployment?right_pad(10)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace5?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].Sex?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace6?right_pad(8)}${.vars["Employee180"].SocialSecurityNumber?right_pad(9)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace7?right_pad(133)}${.vars["Employee180"].BenefitEventDate?right_pad(10)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace8?right_pad(5)}${.vars["Employee180"].BenefitEventReason?right_pad(4)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace9?right_pad(3)}${'\r\n'}-->
     </ftl:template>
</ftl:freemarker>
```

I'm not sure if that's what's making the beginning spaces though, or if it's the actual creation of the .txt. file.  For that I'm doing this:

```
<property expression="fn:concat(get-property('ContractNumber'), get-property('DATE_FOR_FILE'), '.txt')" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint name="FileEpr">
            <address uri="vfs:file:///O:/myTestFolder/WSO2 Testing?transport.vfs.Append=true">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </address>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
```

Any ideas what might be putting those initial spaces in my file?  Or even some handy terms to start googling?  No luck so far in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the whitespaces from your Freemarker template:

```
<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="Employee180">
     <ftl:template>
<!--${.vars["Employee180"].RecordType?right_pad(3)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace1?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].ContractNumber?right_pad(6)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace2?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].EmployeeIDNumber?right_pad(9)?replace("-","")}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace3?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].EmployeeName?right_pad(24)}${.vars["Employee180"].DateOfBirth?right_pad(10)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace4?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].DateOfEmployment?right_pad(10)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace5?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].Sex?right_pad(1)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace6?right_pad(8)}${.vars["Employee180"].SocialSecurityNumber?right_pad(9)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace7?right_pad(133)}${.vars["Employee180"].BenefitEventDate?right_pad(10)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace8?right_pad(5)}${.vars["Employee180"].BenefitEventReason?right_pad(4)}${.vars["Employee180"].BlankSpace9?right_pad(3)}${'\r\n'}-->
     </ftl:template>
</ftl:freemarker>
```

Comment: Hi Claude!  Thanks for the answer!  I tried doing that, but Integration Studio seems to want to undo my edits for the sake of pretty formatting.  I'll try and figure out a way to turn that off in order to REALLY test this out.  Because it's still putting those initial spaces there.

Comment: I'm looking closer at this, and the Employee180 element that I'm applying this padding on is nestled about 3 tags in.  If I count the number of spaces between the beginning of that tag and the beginning of the row, it matches the number of spaces being inserted at the beginning of each row in my text file.  Coincidence?  I dunno...  I'm brand new to ftl, but it's like it took a snapshot of my xml, just removed the tags, and kept the whitespaces where they were and plopped that into my text file.

Comment: Why don't you externalise the template (<ftl:template>employee.ftl</ftl:template>)?

Comment: So I added this in front of my ${.var - <#lt>.  Found it on the freemarker website.  I think lt stands for Left Trim. so now the line looks like this:  <!--<#lt>${.vars["Employee180"}.RecordType.......etc etc